# Xamarin Saving an image and displaying in navigation bar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to save an image to the internal storage of an Android device. Then I want to access it in the shared project for the icons in my navigation bar. The image is coming back from an API. Its giving Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException Resource ID #0x0.

Saving the image:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveImage(string filename, ImageSource img)
    {
        System.IO.Stream outputStream = null;
        bool success = false;

        var renderer = GetHandler(img);
        Bitmap photo = Task.Run(async () => await renderer.LoadImageAsync(img, Forms.Context)).Result;

        string savedImageFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);

        using (outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(savedImageFilename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower() == ".png")
                success = await photo.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outputStream);
            else
                success = await photo.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outputStream);
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Loading the Image:

```
    public FileImageSource LoadImage(string filename)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, MyBlueAssets);
        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, filename);
        FileImageSource image = (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(filePath);

        return image;
    }
```

Accessing and displaying in shared project:

```
DependencyService.Get<IImageCacheDependency>().SaveImage(imageName, Image, count);
FileImageSource loadedImage = DependencyService.Get<IImageCacheDependency ().LoadImage(imageName);

navigation.Icon =  loadedImage;
```

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the saving method I am using. The folder in my Android emulator that I am saving to is empty. Could it have something to do with permission to the folder I am writing to? I am using         string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

Comment: I tested the file path `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocume‌​nts` with files, works fine by my side. I noticed your code `DependencyService.Get<IImageCacheDependency>().SaveImage(imageName, Image, count);`, the `SaveImage` in your code is a task, would you please try to insert a `await` before this code to make it an asynchronous operation and see if your image file is saved successfully?